# Unable to resolve injected configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration, config, app-config

Only in the master branch in our project, a specific service injected in Startup does not resolve when calling a specific controller.
The injected "Service" is just a class with statics filled with configuration values.

In Startup.cs:

```
var azureAdConfiguration = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAD").Get<AzureAdConfiguration>();
services.AddSingleton<IAzureAdConfiguration>(azureAdConfiguration);
```

In the specific controller:

```
private readonly IAzureAdConfiguration _azureAdConfiguration;
public Controller(IConfiguration configuration, IAzureAdConfiguration azureAdConfiguration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _azureAdConfiguration = azureAdConfiguration;
    }
```

I have debugged startup, and the azureAdConfiguration object is properly filled from configuration.
What am i missing here? Why won't this resolve?

Comment: it's a bit of a long shot - but do you reference another class/interface with the same name but different namespace in your controller?

Comment: Oh my god, don't tell anyone... I thought i checked for this, but you were indeed correct. Weird how that is different between two branches of which one was just merged into the other though...